# Scanner invoke String input exemption using .hasNext()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a while loop to add an exemption for scanner input, but cannot figure it out.

I am trying make the below exception and invoke it if the string got size(1).

This is the concept I am trying to build on:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    ArrayList<String> exception = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (keyboard.hasNextString()) {
        exception.add(keyboard.nextString());
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: So, you want to check `if keyboard.nextString().length() == 1`??

Comment: keep getting:error: cannot find symbol
  while (keyboard.hasNextString()) {
                 ^

Comment: @dee_man Did you mean to use `while(keyboard.hasNext())`?

Comment: yes. that's what I am trying to use, trying to catch any string I may get from scanner input. Does that make sense?

Comment: Seriously dee_man, this could have been solved by taking 10 minutes to read the javadoc for `Scanner`.  One minute's reading tells you that there is no `nextString` or `hashNextString`.  Nine more minutes to find the actual methods to use.  Save yourself time by checking the javadocs first ...

Comment: And the easy way to find the javadocs for a class is to Google for them: Google for `javadoc scanner` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In java.util.Scanner there is no such method as "nextString()" or "hasNextString()". Correct me if I'm wrong though.

I think you are trying to use

```
keyboard.hasNext()
```

and

```
keyboard.next()
```

So your full while loop would then be:

```
while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
    exception.add(keyboard.next());
    System.out.println(exception);
}
```

Comment: Then how to catch string input into an arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` does not have any method with the name `hasNextString` or `nextString`. You mistook them for `hasNext` and `next`. The method, `hasNext` is useful when you scan a file but in this case, it is not required.

Given below is how it should be done:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        keyboard.useDelimiter("[\\n\\r]");// Add new line character as delimiter

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String input = "";
        do {
            input = keyboard.next();
            if (input.length() == 1) {
                list.add(input);
            }
        } while (input.length() > 0);

        // Display the list
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
a
Hello
b
c
World
d

[a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're going for here, but this example collects lines of data from the keyboard until the entered value has no length. If the entered value has a length of 1, then it adds it to the exceptions list.  Afterwards, it prints the contents of the exceptions list.

```
List<String> exceptions = new ArrayList<String>();
try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter value: ");
    String exception = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
    if (exception.length() == 1) {
      exceptions.add(exception);
    } else if (exception.length() == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
} 
        
for (String exception : exceptions) {
  System.out.println(exception);
}
```

Hope this was helpful.